# Integral equation $\frac{\phi(x)}n = \binom n {nx}\int_0^1 q^{nx}(1-q)^{n(1-x)}\phi(q)\,dq,\quad \forall x\in[0,1],$

Tags: integral-equations

In [Sewall Wright's Evolution of Mendalian Population](https://www.genetics.org/content/genetics/16/2/97.full.pdf), the equation for the nonrecurrent mutation is
$$\frac{\phi(x)}n = \binom n {nx}\int_0^1 q^{nx}(1-q)^{n(1-x)}\phi(q)\,dq,\quad \forall x\in[0,1],$$
where $n>0$ and $\binom a b$ is the binomial coefficient. We are to solve for a nonzero function $\phi\ne0$. It is an eigenvalue problem of a compact operator. But what is a general method for solving this integral equation? dirichlet  Is there a transform, say Mellin transform, that does the trick?

Comment: Maybe try searching for Fredholm integral equations of the second kind.

Comment: @J.Heller: Yes, it is an homogeneous Fredholm integral equation of the second kind. You can just view it as an eigenfunction problem with eigenvalue of $1$ of a compact operator. However, is there a way to analytically find the solution?